# Visual Studio Community 2015 expiration date

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded the Visual Studio Community 2015 (free version) and I don't see when the expiration date is.

I have tried to see the expiration date at Help Menu -> About Microsoft Visual Studio and there is no expiration date there.

Is there any expiration date (I have a Microsoft account)? If yes, Where can I see it? Or until when is it?

Comment: None. It's free - forever. It's a full version - not a time-crippled demoware

Comment: Nothing is forever with Microsoft, but yes, they are moving towards open-source community and cloud services, and base offline products such as Windows and Visual Studio are slowly becoming free. You pay only for advanced editions or for online services. I wish one day they open-source VS completely.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There is and there isn't an expiration date. If you register Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition by successfully signing into Visual Studio then the product is fully unlocked with no set expiry date. If you don't sign in (or haven't entered a purchased licence key), you only have 30 day evaluation license.

You can check whether your copy of Visual Studio has is registered or not by selecting Help -> About Microsoft Studio and clicking on the "License Status" link in the upper right of the About dialog. If your product isn't registered you'll see something like this:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 License Status Window]

Comment: In my case, with Visual Studio Community 2015, even if I log out and log in, it won't update the license. It comes with the message: "We could not download a license. Please check your network connection or proxy settings." And this message is quite weird, because I am not behind a proxy and the sign in works correctly. Only the license update is not working. Any clues?

Comment: @dannyxyz22 You can try asking a new question. I can only suggest ensuring that you have the latest version of Internet Explorer installed.

Comment: I saw the same message. I tried the 'Check for an updated license', and it rectified itself. I am not sure if it was just a temporary glitch or if clicking that was the actual fix though.

Comment: The license seems to stay even after I log out, so that's just a one-time activation.

Answer (score 31):

Visual Studio Community 2015 is free. But I got the 30 day trial expired message. After some googling figured out that I have to sign in with a Microsoft account. So I signed up with my Hotmail account and after that I was able to continue using the VS community 2015.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple approach to sneak by that stupid blocker screen in Visual Studio after 30-days expires using **Process Hacker**:

[image: VS2015 Trial]

Details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243422/3135511

It's more of a quick 'n dirty fix than a real solution. However, it may be quicker than doing all that official login/sign up, subscribe, whatever crap Microsoft wants you to do, in order to use Visual Studio Community Version for free.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Link is broken. But still i resolved this issue with my own trick. Just change the system date to some **30 days back**. Close and reopen visual studio. Congrats,You are able to access now.

Answer (score 4):

I am running VSCommunity 2015 in Win8.1 virtual machine installed inside a Parallels 11 virtual machine installed on my Mac OSX El Capitan. To my surprise and delight it installed and ran fine. I used it for 2 weeks without signing into my Microsoft account. I tried to login 6 weeks later and got the 30 day trial screen shown above.

However for me I was able to simply click on the link above shown as "Check for an updated license" and was prompted in to log in to my Microsoft account. I did so and it granted me a license successfully and was seamless. Now under License Status it displays as "This product is licensed to: ".

*I guess I got lucky as I'm guessing this is how it is supposed to work.*

*[sidebar]:
Over the decades I've disliked most MS products but have been out of the VS IDE development tools game for awhile, and I have to say using VSComm15 has been flawless. Using it to learn C# and the IDE itself for a new contract job and it worked perfectly and has great features.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use "RunasDate" to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an expiration date for the community edition.

The usage section from the from [the Visual Studio website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) clearly states:

**For individuals**

> Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create
>   their own free or paid apps.

**For organizations**

> An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual
>   Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning
>   environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source
>   projects.
>
> For all other usage scenarios:  In non-enterprise organizations, up to
>   five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise
>   organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars
>   in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source,
>   academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios
>   described above.

Comment: There is an expiration date. It just doesn't require money to activate, just a free account. See the better answers below.

Comment: If you still have an expiration issue, please [follow this link](http://dotnetable.com/2014/10/10/switching-microsoft-account-user-in-visual-studio-2013/) for how to resolve it. I used `Method 3` to resolve my issue.

Comment: There in fact *is* an evaluation period, after which you have to create an account.

Comment: i am getting annoying message after 30 days and unable to work on visual studio. I created an account but do not really know what to do now in order to remove the license expired pop up when i start VS

Answer (score 1):

In case you had enabled 2-Step verification for your Microsoft account disable it when updating the VS License using the 'Check for Updated License' option provided in the window.

Answer (score 1):

I also get same issue after I repair vs2015, even I click check license online, still fail. 
Correct action is:
1. Sign out
2. Check License Status, then it will pop-up login window, after login then it able to successfully get the license info.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even after sign up to Visual Studio account, I cant sign in and the license still expired.

Solution from across the internet:
Download iso version of the installer.
Then run installer, select repair. That would solve the problem for most case.

In my case, I got an iso version of ms Visual Studio 2013. Installed it and I can successfully sign in and its forever free.

Comment: In my case, with Visual Studio Community 2015, even if I log in, it won't update the license. It comes with the message: "We could not download a license. Please check your network connection or proxy settings." And this message is quite weird, because I am not behind a proxy and the sign in works correctly. Only the license update is not working. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instructions for the problem:

> You can evaluate Visual Studio for free up to 30 days.
>
> To Unlock Visual Studio using an online subscription

[Link Microsoft account to Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx)

I have encountered this problem:
[image]

Possible solution can be found at the link above.

> This message indicates that while your subscription may still be valid, the license token Visual Studio uses to keep your subscription up to date hasn’t been refreshed and has gone stale due to one of the following reasons:
> You have not used Visual Studio or have had no internet connection for an extend period of time.
> You signed out of Visual Studio.

Comment: I assume that the token will go stale only for Enterprise and Professional version, not for Community version? This question is about Visual Studio Community.

Comment: I have outlook.com.after signout and login to google account .community licence activated