# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't work anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Suddenly Visual Studio tells me that my trial period is over, but I am pretty sure it's free. Can anyone enlighten me?

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1317x.jpg)

Comment: yeah try and sign in with microsoft account, and when installng the visual studio do u input ur activation code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Community 2015 expiration date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235116/visual-studio-community-2015-expiration-date)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's free, but you need to sign in to continue to use it for free. Read message better on the right side of picture.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to sign in with a Microsoft Account.